# What framework to use for development of a photoalbum app using pygobject

Tags: python, gtk3, cairo, vala, clutter

I am planning to develop a photo album app in GTK3 using Python. It typically has multiple "pages" per "album" with multiple photos per page. These photo's can be arranges on the page, partly overlapping each other, rotated, resized, etc. Each photo can have a choice of borders. Each page can have a choice of background. It needs to be able to be printed as an album or exported as an web based album. You get the idea..

Now, I am completely overwhelmed with the choices of libraries/frameworks that exist: Cairo and it's choice of canvases: https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/ProjectRidley/CanvasOverview/Canvases, GDK, GSK, GTK itself, clutter, and I probably forgot some.

Starting fresh, with no technical debt involved, what is the best suited framework for this type of app in terms of features, stability and future?

Btw, if needed, I would consider switching from Python to Vala.

Comment: Better ask at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, stackoverflow is the wrong place for such a question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just copied it there.